# How do I set up the showLicensePage function to work with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wrapping up an ios app I am creating and realized I need to display the Flutter License somewhere in my settings screen.

I am trying to implement the `showLicensePage` function from Flutter but not sure how to go about this. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showLicensePage.html

How do I use this function?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FlutterLicense extends StatelessWidget {
  void showLicensePage({
    @required BuildContext context,
    String applicationName,
    String applicationVersion,
    Widget applicationIcon,
    String applicationLegalese,
    bool useRootNavigator = false,
  }) {
    assert(context != null);
    assert(useRootNavigator != null);
    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: useRootNavigator)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => LicensePage(
        applicationName: applicationName,
        applicationVersion: applicationVersion,
        applicationIcon: applicationIcon,
        applicationLegalese: applicationLegalese,
      ),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0XFFeb1555),
        title: Text(
          'LICENSES',
          style: TextStyle(),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              children: showLicensePage(context: null),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

1. You are passing `null` to as the `context` parameter which is wrong. Do `showLicensePage(context: context)` instead.
2. The `showLicensePage` is a function which returns null so you cannot pass it as the `children` of the `Column`.
3. You do not need a dedicated widget to display your licenses page. The framework takes care of it for you.

#### Solution

On your settings page, you may have a widget on which when clicked, shows the license page. Just call the function `showLicensePage(context: context)` inside the `onTap` or `onPressed` of that widget.

#### Example

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showLicensePage(
              context: context,
              // applicationIcon: Image.asset(name)
              // applicationName: "App Name"
              // Other parameters
            );
          },
          child: Text('Show Licenses'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code produces, this when the button is clicked:
[image: Licence Page]

Comment: Thank you very much Akora! I really appreciate it. I got it working. THANK YOU!

Comment: Quick question for you! My ThemeData scaffoldBackgroundColor in my main.dart file is set to black. So when this Flutter License displays it cant be read because it's black text. Is there anyway to customize the text color? Or override my theme background color? Thanks!

Comment: Not so sure about that. It automatically inherits it's theme data from the MaterialApp

Comment: thank you. no worries,  yes i am attempting to edit that.